# How to define array in asp.net nested array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

Use in php

```
$_array=array(
             1=>array("id"=>1,"name"=>"abc"),
             2=>array("id"=>2,"name"=>"vbn")

);
echo $_array[1]["id"];
```

How to use asp.net c#?

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not code-conversion tool. Please add your c# code and describe what problems do you have with it

Comment: ASP.NET doesn't have arrays. It's a web framework. C# does and all you need to do is specify the dimentions. If you have to ask how to define an array though, you should probably be looking for a C# tutorial.

Comment: BTW, what you posted looks more like an array of *object*s, not a nested array. PHP has objects, so why use arrays? You should create a class with ID and Name properties and define a `MyClass[]` array or `List<MyClass>` list.

Comment: this is php, not c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c# you should do something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p1 = new Person(1, "abc");
        Person p2 = new Person(2, "vbn");
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
        list.Add(p1);
        list.Add(p2);
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public Person(int id, string name)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

}
```